# How to use pandas INPUT function to get a list of customers

Tags: python, pandas, input

I have created a code to get users of my platform based on 2 things:

- choiceTitle: search for a specific word contained in the title of an Ad that users of my platform have looked at. For eg, the Ad is "We are offering free Gin" and I want to get the word 'Gin'
- PrimaryTagPreviousChoice: the Ad has a "Food and Drink" tag

I can get those users who are interested in Gin and Food and Drink with:

(df2['choiceTitle'].str.contains("(?i)Gin")) & (df2['PrimaryTagPreviousChoice'].str.contains("(?i)Food and Drink"))

What I'd like to do is create a function with all my code inside (hence the sql query, the rename operation, the sort_values ​​operation etc....)  and then use the INPUT function. So I'll just have to run my code, so that python will ask me 2 questions:

- choiceTitle? ... Gin
- PrimaryTagPreviousChoice? ...Food and Drink.

I enter the 2 options and it gives me the users interested in, let's say, Gin and Food and Drink.

How can I do it?

MY CODE:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(""" select etc..... """, con)
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(""" select etc..... """, con)

df1['user_id'] = df1['user_id'].apply(str)

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on='user_id', right_on='user_id', how='left')


tag = df2[
    
    (df2['choiceTitle'].str.contains("(?i)Gin")) & 
    (df2['PrimaryTagPreviousChoice'].str.contains("(?i)Food and Drink"))
     ]


dw = tag[['user', 'title', 'user_category', 'email', 'last_login', 
          'PrimaryTagPreviousChoice', 'choiceTitle'
         ]].drop_duplicates()



dw = dw.sort_values(['last_login'], ascending=[False])

dw = dw[dw.last_login > dt.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("30day")]

dw = dw.rename({'user': 'user full name', 'title': 'user title'}
               , axis='columns')

dw.drop_duplicates(subset ="Email", 
                     keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Adding a function in Python is simple. Just use the def keyword to declare the function and put your existing code under it (indented). Put parameters in the parenthesis.

Here is the updated code:

```
def GetUsers (title, tag)
    df = pd.read_sql_query(""" select etc..... """, con)
    df1 = pd.read_sql_query(""" select etc..... """, con)

    df1['user_id'] = df1['user_id'].apply(str)

    df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on='user_id', right_on='user_id', how='left')

    tag = df2[            
        (df2['choiceTitle'].str.contains("(?i)" + title)) &   
        (df2['PrimaryTagPreviousChoice'].str.contains("(?i)" + tag))]

    dw = tag[['user', 'title', 'user_category', 'email', 'last_login', 
              'PrimaryTagPreviousChoice', 'choiceTitle'
             ]].drop_duplicates()

    dw = dw.sort_values(['last_login'], ascending=[False])

    dw = dw[dw.last_login > dt.datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("30day")]

    dw = dw.rename({'user': 'user full name', 'title': 'user title'}
                   , axis='columns')

    dw.drop_duplicates(subset ="Email", 
                         keep = 'first', inplace = True) 
    return dw  # send back to print statement


# get input from user
inpTitle = input ("choiceTitle? ")
inpTag = input ("PrimaryTagPreviousChoice? ")

# run function
result = GetUsers (inpTitle, inpTag)

print(result)
```

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Save your `input()` as variables and use string concatenation to edit your mask. Note that an additional set of `{}` is needed for escaping.

```
choiceTitle = input('choiceTitle?')
PrimaryTagPreviousChoice = input('PrimaryTagPreviousChoice?')

mask = df2[(df2['choiceTitle'].str.contains("(?i){{0}}".format(choiceTitle))) & 
           (df2['PrimaryTagPreviousChoice'].str.contains("(?i) 
           {{0}}".format(PrimaryTagPreviousChoice)))]

dw = mask[['user', 'title', 'user_category', 'email', 'last_login', 
          'PrimaryTagPreviousChoice', 'choiceTitle'
         ]].drop_duplicates()

....
```